# MUI date picker opens at year 1900 if maxDate is set

Tags: material-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to build a date picker using `mui/x-date-picker` where the UI opens to the year picker first. I'm also trying to limit the selectable year range with `maxDate`.

Without `maxDate` set, the year picker opens with the year 2023 selected by default and the year 2023 visible. With `maxDate` set (e.g. to 2007) the year picker correctly limits the selectable years BUT it opens at 1900 instead of the most recent valid year.

[image]

I've searched the docs extensively but I haven't found a way to change this behavior, nor have I found a way to put the years in descending order which would also work to fix this issue.

Minimal reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-x-date-picker-1900-vngnhq?file=/src/App.js

Is there a way to have the year picker open at the year of the provided `maxDate`? And if not, is there a way to display the years in descending order?

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't see any way to do quite what you want. There isn't any way to [reverse the years](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/v6.3.0/packages/x-date-pickers/src/YearCalendar/YearCalendar.tsx#L256) and the focused year (which it automatically scrolls to) is either the [selected year or "today" year](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/v6.3.0/packages/x-date-pickers/src/YearCalendar/YearCalendar.tsx#L128). "Selected" is based on the `value` which you don't want to specify and the "today" year is beyond your max.

Answer (score 2):

The picker is getting the value null at the first load from the inital state, so try to pass this to avoid sending null and select the date you want as a default value:

```
value={value || dayjs().year(2010)}
```

Comment: Thanks, this could work however I would not like to set a default value, or at least not display it. Since I'm using it as a date of birth picker it wouldn't be a good user experience to have a default value.